# android devolpment linking buttons to other xml pages

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm developing an app for android. The main screen has 6 buttons. Each button leads to another screen. I'm having trouble with the code to make the buttons do anything when clicked. this is what I have:
on the main page my button id is glass the page opened when clicked is glass.xml

```
android:onClick="Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);"
```

and my scr folder I have the java activities FirstActivity.java

```
package install.fineline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fine_line);

    Button btnload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.glass);
    btnload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

and SecondActivity.java

```
package install.fineline;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.glass);


}
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On the button definition in the xml remove the `onClick` attribute.

The button click action is set in code so it doesn't need to be in the xml file.

There is sample code [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) showing how to do what you want.

Comment: i added a link above to an example. this should help get what you need.